# When scaling a pod, will Kubernetes start new pods on more available nodes?

Tags: kubernetes

I tried to find a clear answer to this, and I'm sure it's in the kubernetes documentation somewhere but I couldn't find it.

If I have 4 nodes in my cluster, and am running a compute intensive pod which presumably uses up all/most of the resources on a single node, and I scale that pod to 4 replicas- will Kubernetes put those new pods on the unused nodes automatically?

Or, in the case where that compute intensive pod is not actually crunching numbers at the time but I scale the pod to 4 replicas (ie: node running the original pod has plenty of 'available' resources) will kubernetes still see that there are 3 other totally free nodes and start the pods on them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kubernetes will schedule the new pods on any node with sufficient resources. So one of the newly created pods could end up on a node were one is already running, if the node has enough resources left.

You can use an anti affinity to prevent pods from scheduling on the same node as a pod from the same deployment, e.g. by using the development's label

```
podAntiAffinity:
      preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - weight: 100
        podAffinityTerm:
          labelSelector:
            matchExpressions:
            - key: resources-group
              operator: In
              values:
              - high
          topologyKey: topology.kubernetes.io/zone
```

Read [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#inter-pod-affinity-and-anti-affinity) for more on that topic.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, it depends on the scheduler configuration.
If you are running your on-premise kubernetes cluster and you have access to the scheduler process, you can tune the policy as you prefer (see [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/kube-scheduler/)).

Otherwise, you can only play with the pod resource requests/limits and anti-affinity (see [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/)).

Comment: Thanks!  That seems to be what I was looking for.  The scheduler may help as well, but in the affinity section it talks about 'never co-located' pods, so that no two pods will be assigned to the same pod.  You set me on the right path, although I had to mark the other answer as the solution, it has a little more explanation/code example.